# scope.$watch in angular directive running after data in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have a controller that reads in some csv data:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  d3.csv('data.csv', function(err, rows){
    // add id field to each row
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      rows.forEach(function(r, i){
        r['id'] = 'a' + padString(i, 3, '0');
      });
      $scope.data = rows;
    });
  });
});
```

And a directive that uses it:

```
app.directive('ngbarChart', function(){
  function link(scope, el, attr){

    scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
      if(newVal) {
        console.log('new stuff! now we can do useful things!')
      }
    }, true);

  }
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    scope: {
      data: '='
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ngbar-chart data="data"></ngbar-chart>
</div>
```

But! the callback in `scope.$watch` only runs once - before the controller has finished loading data and passing it into `$scope.data`.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try wrapping your link function in a `$timeout`?

Comment: When do you want the code to execute exactly? You might want something different than `$scope.$watch`? Also, please specify angular version in case you can use newer lifecycle hooks :)

Comment: Why isn't the data assignment inside the apply block?

Comment: @GBa - it is. I indented poorly. Edited.

Comment: @BlazeBiker I'm using 1.5.  I want the callback of the watch function to execute after the controller has finished reading the csv file and passed that data to the $scope

Comment: Maybe check into using [lifecycle hooks from the $compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)